# Where can I find a Pathfinder character sheet that works in Libreoffice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-sheets

Where can I find a Pathfinder character sheet that works in [Libreoffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) spreadsheet (the new Openoffice)?

Comment: I did a quick search for LibreOffice, and it looks like it's compatable with both Open Office formats and Microsoft Office formats, so if you find one that works in those it should work in LibreOffice. [LibreOffice Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice#Supported_formats)

Comment: Well, it's SOMEWHAT compatible. Enough is different so that sCoreForge fails, as the links between different pages in Excel is different than LibreOffice and OpenOffice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by [DForck42](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1914/dforck42) in the question comments, [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) is compatible with the Open Office document format (.odt).

With regards to that, I have found:

- [Open Office Character Sheet](http://igor.rock-clan.de/d20tools/) - Several options here, including a sample character and sheets with both calculated statistics and plain, under the *Pathfinder™ Character Sheet* heading.  There are some snags, mentioned in the *Miscellaneous* section at the bottom of the page.
- [Tyranscooter's Open Office Calc Character Sheet](https://www.adnddownloads.com/en/resource/interactive-character-sheet-v14) - "An Open Office Calc based character sheet intended for use at the gaming table. In addition to the basics, it also tracks the effects and durations of all your favorite buff spells, feats and special abilities."

However, neither [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) nor [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) are fully compatible with Excel macro-using, multi-tabbed spreadsheets. For example,

> An important difference between Excel and Calc regarding functions is that the values supplied to a function (which are called arguments in Excel and parameters in Calc) have different separators. Calc always uses semicolons to separate parameters in a function. Excel uses either commas or semicolons, depending on the system (for example commas on English systems, semicolons on German systems). Calc will generate a “#NAME?” error if you use a comma in place of a semi-colon. [6](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/UserGuide/Migration_Guide/Calc_and_Excel)

and

> However, if you use a lot of Excel macros and programming, then you're going to struggle with Calc. The reason is that Calc has its own macro language and it's not always compatible with Excel's VBA format. This means if you're trying to switch over to Calc from Excel, you may need to redo a lot of your macros. [7](http://lifehacker.com/battle-of-the-office-suites-microsoft-office-and-libre-1147940828)

That means the original [sCoreForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scoreforge) and the [forked version](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/3vkims/new_versions_of_scoreforge_and_scorespell/) will require much conversion work to make them work in [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) or [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org).